# Incorrect key file Mysql error

Tags: linux, mysql

An interesting mysql error has popped up on an ExpressionEngine site I'm running recently. When trying to access the admin control panel I get the following mysql error:

```
Error Number: 126

Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_XXX_XX.MYI'; try to repair it
```

It's a VPS and I have root access. Confusingly, there appears not to be any such file in the /tmp/ directory. A bit of googling has shown me that it could be an issue with space on this partition but the tmp folder is almost empty (only a few k) and I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do next. Repairing said table also yielded no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort this out I changed the location of the mysql tmp directory in /etc/mysql/my.cnf then restarted mysql. All is now well.

Comment: Please come back in a few days and mark this answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

That table can be deleted. It is a temporary table and it is probably very old by now (a minutes old). /tmp was proabably full at the time the table was being made, especially if other apps were writing to /tmp as well.

Look into having your hosting provider setup another disk within the VPS and then configure MySQL's tmpdir variable to point to that new disk.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I ended up moving the tmp dir and restarting mysql which seems to have sorted things out.